# Add client-side library to a scaffold

Tags: javascript, aem

I'm new to AEM.

I have successfully set up a client-side library before for the output page of a scaffold, but now I need to add a client-side library to do validation of the scaffold itself.

There's no HTML for me to stick my tags in to suck in the client library, so how do I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are loading the scaffold and how you are doing the validation.  If you are loading it via an HTTP call you can still reference the client library URL, but if you are loading it via a file reference you will need to individually reference the JavaScript files that are included in the client library.

I had to do this for running Jasmine unit tests on our JavaScript via Karma.  For this I had to reference the script files from the source code directory directly.  You won't be getting the combined & minified script, but the logic should be unchanged if the files are referenced in the same order as they are included in the client library.

I may be misunderstanding your question, so if you could clarify what you mean by a scaffold that may help.